# Titanium Studio does not open after install

Tags: android, eclipse, titanium-mobile

A Java Runtime Environment(JRE) or Java Development(JDK) must be available in order to run Titanium Studio. no Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:users\user\Appdata\Roaming\TitaniumStudio\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current Path

i have already have eclipse for android application development. But mobile application development with titanium studio i am totally beginner. I have installed titanium by following [http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start][1]

Comment: Do you have a suitable JRE in your path? The error is suggesting you do not.

Comment: thnx but other problem that jdk 32/64 bit problem that cause jni shared library jvm dll. trying to fix it.